# in box2d how to decrease joint's reaction force?

Tags: box2d

I'm trying to make a game like **cut the rope** and meet some problems.
when I create a float bubble and connect with a rope(a sets of bodies connected with revoluteJoint), the rope will become longer and when I destroy the bubble,rope gives a a big reaction force to candy, so how to decrease this reaction force?
to simulate bubble's floating, I did this

```
class Bubble extends PhyObject
{
     override function draw():void{
         if(this.combined){
            this.getBody().SetLinearVelocity(velocity);//velocity=new b2Vec2(0,-3.5);
         }
     }
     //other code
}
class Main{
    public function loop(){
        getAllPhyObject().forEach(function(phyObj){
              phyobj.draw();
        });
    }

}
```

so if bubble was combined with candy ,It "float".
I think maybe I can do this
pseudo code:

```
if(bubble is connected with rope)
{
    //dynamic adjust bubble's linear velocity with rope's reaction force
}
```

but I just cannot figure out how to dynamic adjust bubble's linear velocity.and is there a simpler way to solve this problem?
thanks!
**update**
finally I solved my problem,so I write it down and hope it help to you.
below code is grab from b2BuoyancyController and it works in my case.

```
    //buoyancy
    private function float():void {
        if (bodies.length < 1)
            return;
        var body:b2Body = bodies[0];
        if(body.IsAwake() == false){
            //Buoyancy force is just a function of position,
            //so unlike most forces, it is safe to ignore sleeping bodes
            return;
        }
        var normal:b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2(0, -1);
        var offset:Number = 20;
        var density:Number = 2;
        var velocity:b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2(0, 0);
        var linearDrag:Number = 2;
        var angularDrag:Number = 1;
        var gravity:b2Vec2 = toolkit.world.GetGravity().Copy();
        var areac:b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2();
        var massc:b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2();
        var area:Number = 0.0;
        var mass:Number = 0.0;
        for(var fixture:b2Fixture=body.GetFixtureList();fixture;fixture=fixture.GetNext()){
            var sc:b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2();
            var sarea:Number = fixture.GetShape().ComputeSubmergedArea(normal, offset, body.GetTransform(), sc);
            area += sarea;
            areac.x += sarea * sc.x;
            areac.y += sarea * sc.y;
            var shapeDensity:Number = 1;
            mass += sarea*shapeDensity;
            massc.x += sarea * sc.x * shapeDensity;
            massc.y += sarea * sc.y * shapeDensity;
        }
        areac.x/=area;
        areac.y/=area;
        massc.x/=mass;
        massc.y/=mass;
        if(area<Number.MIN_VALUE)
            return;
        //Buoyancy
        var buoyancyForce:b2Vec2 = gravity.GetNegative();
        buoyancyForce.Multiply(density*area)
        body.ApplyForce(buoyancyForce,massc);
        //Linear drag
        var dragForce:b2Vec2 = body.GetLinearVelocityFromWorldPoint(areac);
        dragForce.Subtract(velocity);
        dragForce.Multiply(-linearDrag*area);
        body.ApplyForce(dragForce, areac);

        //tmpForce
        if(candy.bodies.length>0){ //TODO 你妹!!!!!
            var tmpForce:b2Vec2 = candy.bodies[0].GetLinearVelocity();
            body.SetLinearVelocity(tmpForce);
            //tmpForce.x = 0;
            //tmpForce.Subtract(velocity);
            //tmpForce.Multiply(-linearDrag*area);
            body.ApplyForce(tmpForce, areac);
        }
        //Angular drag
        //TODO: Something that makes more physical sense?
        body.ApplyTorque(-body.GetInertia()/body.GetMass()*area*body.GetAngularVelocity()*angularDrag)
    }
```

tips:use force instated of impulse and changing linear velocity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit in box2D configuration file, but the main problem is with how you implemented bubble. The rope length should always be a less than a value, meaning it shouldn't become longer to give that big reaction in the first place.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I have to clarify my question, I just use normal b2body ,and set it's linear Velocity to a fixed value in main loop

Comment: @ifree try using addforce instead of directly setting velocity.

Comment: still not work,and when add force It moves weird

Comment: In each time step I called b2d.clearForces(),if I don't clear forces i think there would be something strange